# duda acerca de background-clip

Tags: css3

estaba aprendiendo la propiedad background-clip en la documentacion de mozilla
y dice lo siguiente.

> Si la imagen o color de fondo no esta definido, esta propiedad solo
>   tendrá un efecto visual cuando el borde tenga regiones transparentes o
>   regiones parcialmente opacas (debido a border-style o border-image);
>   de lo contrario el borde cubre la diferencia.

fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

cuando el borde tiene regiones transparentes o parcialmente opacas no es al contrario de lo que dice o estoy entendiendo algo mal?, es decir no deberia ser que el efecto de background-clip tiene efecto visual cuando hay bordes descontinuos o con regiones parcialmente opacas y el color de fondo esta definido.

porque si yo no le doy color de fondo ni nada a mi elemento, el background de ese elemento es transparent por defecto y el background-clip no me presenta nada... pero el sitio me dice que si la imagen o color de fondo no esta definido el background-clip tendrá efecto cuando el borde tiene regiones transparentes o parcialmente opacas...

```css
body{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
   border: 15px rgba(55,55,22,0.5);
   border-style: dotted double;
   margin: 2em;
   padding: 2em;
 
}
.border-box { background-clip: border-box; }
.padding-box { background-clip: padding-box; }
.content-box { background-clip: content-box; }
```

```html
<p class="border-box">The yellow background extends behind the border.</p>
<p class="padding-box">The yellow background extends to the inside edge of the border.</p>
<p class="content-box">The yellow background extends only to the edge of the content box.</p>
```

Comment: La verdad es que esa explicación no tiene sentido o me estoy perdiendo algo. Opino como tú que si el elemento no tiene fondo no hay nada que recortar y no se mostrará nada